# How to permanently store wolfram connector credentials?

Tags: webservices, serviceexecute

Every time I launch a new frontend session  I have to reenter my credentials. Anyway around this?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you were check the box labeled 'Save Connection`, you might not have fill out this dialog the next time you connect.

Comment: Nope that box don't do nothin

Comment: Have you tried using `ServiceConnect` and serialising the `ServiceObject` it returns by `Export` of `"MX"` or `"WDX"`.  When `Import`ed can the `ServiceObject` be used without reentering your credentials?

Comment: @Edmund could you explain this in an answer?

Comment: @M.R. I tried it with `"LinkedId"` and it didn't work. You can export to `"MX"` (perhaps also `"WDX"`) and import into a new notebook in a new context and it will import connected. However, if you restart *Mathematica* and import it will come in as disconnected.  I think it drops all connections when the frontend exits.